# Different types of multiplication in ANTLR4 grammar

Tags: math, expression, antlr4

While entering mathematical expressions that are parsed with ANTLR4 both types of multiplication `5 * x` and `5x` should be allowed. The grammar below has accepted both cases but there is a new negation rule that produces wrong output. Example: the expression `x^2 - 5x` is now parsed as if it were `(x^2) * (-5x)`.

How should I change the grammar so that it correctly parses the input?

EDIT: I have updated the grammar below so that it reflects the current state and I have also inserted here the log messages to show my problem. The main problem is that there is no `enterNatural (5)` and `enterVariable (x)` call before the `exitSimpleMultiplication (5x)` call.

**EDIT2**: I have been playing with the grammar a lot and have found that it gets better if I use rules in `simplifiedMultiplication` (instead of tokens). Updated grammer posted below.

Now, parsing `5x` is working but parsing `2x^2` is still not (it results in `(2x)^2`, s. log messages below).

I have also posted the listener class.

```
// Parser Rules

expression
    : primary                                            # aPrimary
    | composite                                          # aComposite
    | expression '^' expression                          # exponentiation
    | '-' expression                                     # negation
    | expression '/' expression                          # division
    | expression '*' expression                          # multiplication
    | simpleMultiplication                               # aSimpleMultiplication
    | expression operator=('+' | '-') expression         # additive
    | expression '=' expression                          # equation
    ;

primary
    : NATURAL                                            # natural
    | VARIABLE                                           # variable
    ;

composite
    : '(' expression ')'                                 # parentheses
    | '|' expression '|'                                 # abs
    | function                                           # aFunction
    ;

simpleMultiplication
    : primary primary
    | primary composite
    | composite primary
    | composite composite
    ;

function
    : FUNC '(' expression ')'
    ;

// Lexer Rules

FUNC : 'sqrt' | 'exp' | 'ln' | 'log' | 'abs' ;

ADD  : '+' ;
SUB  : '-' ;

NATURAL : [0-9]+ ;

VARIABLE : 'x' ;

WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Listener class:

```
public class AntlrExpressionListener extends ExpressionsBaseListener {

    private final Deque<Expression> stack = new LinkedList();

    private final Map<String, Expression> identifiers = new HashMap();

    private Variable x;

    /**
     * Returns the parsed expression.
     * 
     * @return 
     */
    Expression getExpression() {
        return stack.pop();
    }

    void add(Reference ref) {
        identifiers.put(ref.name(), ref);
    }

    @Override
    public void exitAdditive(ExpressionsParser.AdditiveContext ctx) {
        Expression rhs = stack.pop();
        Expression lhs = stack.pop();

        if (ctx.operator.getType() == ExpressionsParser.ADD) {
            stack.push(Sum.add(lhs, rhs));
        } else if (ctx.operator.getType() == ExpressionsParser.SUB) {
            stack.push(Sum.subtract(lhs, rhs));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected operation: " + ctx.operator);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exitMultiplication(ExpressionsParser.MultiplicationContext ctx) {
        Expression rhs = stack.pop();
        Expression lhs = stack.pop();

        stack.push(new Multiplication(lhs, rhs));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitSimpleMultiplication(ExpressionsParser.SimpleMultiplicationContext ctx) {
        Expression rhs = stack.pop();
        Expression lhs = stack.pop();

        stack.push(new Multiplication(lhs, rhs));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitDivision(ExpressionsParser.DivisionContext ctx) {
        Expression rhs = stack.pop();
        Expression lhs = stack.pop();

        if (lhs instanceof IntegerNumber && rhs instanceof NaturalNumber) {
            stack.push(new Division(lhs, rhs).evaluate());
        } else {
            stack.push(new Division(lhs, rhs));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exitExponentiation(ExpressionsParser.ExponentiationContext ctx) {
        Expression rhs = stack.pop();
        Expression lhs = stack.pop();

        stack.push(new Exponentiation(lhs, rhs));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitNegation(ExpressionsParser.NegationContext ctx) {
        Expression arg = stack.pop();

        if (arg instanceof ANumber) {
            stack.push(((ANumber) arg).negate());
        } else {
            stack.push(new Negation(arg));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exitEquation(ExpressionsParser.EquationContext ctx) {
        Expression rhs = stack.pop();
        Expression lhs = stack.pop();
        Equality equation = new Equality(lhs, rhs);

        stack.push(Equation.convert(equation, x));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitFunction(ExpressionsParser.FunctionContext ctx) {
        String function = ctx.FUNC().getText();
        Expression arg = stack.pop();

        switch (function) {
            case "exp":
                stack.push(new Exp(arg));
                break;

            case "ln":
                stack.push(new Ln(arg));
                break;

            case "sqrt":
                stack.push(new Sqrt(arg));
                break;

            case "abs":
                stack.push(new Abs(arg));
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected function name: " + function);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void enterNatural(ExpressionsParser.NaturalContext ctx) {
        stack.push(Naturals.getInstance().create(ctx.getText()));
    }

    @Override
    public void enterVariable(ExpressionsParser.VariableContext ctx) {
        x = (Variable) identifiers.get(ctx.getText());

        if (x == null) {
            x = Numbers.variable(ctx.getText());
            identifiers.put(ctx.getText(), x);
        }

        stack.push(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void exitAbs(ExpressionsParser.AbsContext ctx) {
        Expression arg = stack.pop();

        stack.push(new Abs(arg));
    }

    @Override
    public void enterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) {
        System.out.printf("in:  %s : %s%n", ctx.getText(), ctx.toStringTree());
    }

    @Override
    public void exitEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) {
        System.out.printf("out: %s : %s%n", ctx.getText(), ctx.toStringTree());
    }
}
```

Log messages:

```
in:  2x^2-x-1=0 : ([] ([0] ([0 0] ([0 0 0] ([0 0 0 0] ([15 0 0 0 0] ([53 15 0 0 0 0] 2) ([54 15 0 0 0 0] x))) ^ ([20 0 0 0] ([13 20 0 0 0] 2))) - ([29 0 0] ([13 29 0 0] x))) - ([29 0] ([13 29 0] 1))) = ([32] ([13 32] 0)))
in:  2x^2-x-1 : ([0] ([0 0] ([0 0 0] ([0 0 0 0] ([15 0 0 0 0] ([53 15 0 0 0 0] 2) ([54 15 0 0 0 0] x))) ^ ([20 0 0 0] ([13 20 0 0 0] 2))) - ([29 0 0] ([13 29 0 0] x))) - ([29 0] ([13 29 0] 1)))
in:  2x^2-x : ([0 0] ([0 0 0] ([0 0 0 0] ([15 0 0 0 0] ([53 15 0 0 0 0] 2) ([54 15 0 0 0 0] x))) ^ ([20 0 0 0] ([13 20 0 0 0] 2))) - ([29 0 0] ([13 29 0 0] x)))
in:  2x^2 : ([0 0 0] ([0 0 0 0] ([15 0 0 0 0] ([53 15 0 0 0 0] 2) ([54 15 0 0 0 0] x))) ^ ([20 0 0 0] ([13 20 0 0 0] 2)))
in:  2x : ([0 0 0 0] ([15 0 0 0 0] ([53 15 0 0 0 0] 2) ([54 15 0 0 0 0] x)))
in:  2x : ([15 0 0 0 0] ([53 15 0 0 0 0] 2) ([54 15 0 0 0 0] x))
in:  2 : ([53 15 0 0 0 0] 2)
out: 2 : ([53 15 0 0 0 0] 2)
in:  x : ([54 15 0 0 0 0] x)
out: x : ([54 15 0 0 0 0] x)
out: 2x : ([15 0 0 0 0] ([53 15 0 0 0 0] 2) ([54 15 0 0 0 0] x))
out: 2x : ([0 0 0 0] ([15 0 0 0 0] ([53 15 0 0 0 0] 2) ([54 15 0 0 0 0] x)))
in:  2 : ([20 0 0 0] ([13 20 0 0 0] 2))
in:  2 : ([13 20 0 0 0] 2)
out: 2 : ([13 20 0 0 0] 2)
out: 2 : ([20 0 0 0] ([13 20 0 0 0] 2))
out: 2x^2 : ([0 0 0] ([0 0 0 0] ([15 0 0 0 0] ([53 15 0 0 0 0] 2) ([54 15 0 0 0 0] x))) ^ ([20 0 0 0] ([13 20 0 0 0] 2)))
in:  x : ([29 0 0] ([13 29 0 0] x))
in:  x : ([13 29 0 0] x)
out: x : ([13 29 0 0] x)
out: x : ([29 0 0] ([13 29 0 0] x))
out: 2x^2-x : ([0 0] ([0 0 0] ([0 0 0 0] ([15 0 0 0 0] ([53 15 0 0 0 0] 2) ([54 15 0 0 0 0] x))) ^ ([20 0 0 0] ([13 20 0 0 0] 2))) - ([29 0 0] ([13 29 0 0] x)))
in:  1 : ([29 0] ([13 29 0] 1))
in:  1 : ([13 29 0] 1)
out: 1 : ([13 29 0] 1)
out: 1 : ([29 0] ([13 29 0] 1))
out: 2x^2-x-1 : ([0] ([0 0] ([0 0 0] ([0 0 0 0] ([15 0 0 0 0] ([53 15 0 0 0 0] 2) ([54 15 0 0 0 0] x))) ^ ([20 0 0 0] ([13 20 0 0 0] 2))) - ([29 0 0] ([13 29 0 0] x))) - ([29 0] ([13 29 0] 1)))
in:  0 : ([32] ([13 32] 0))
in:  0 : ([13 32] 0)
out: 0 : ([13 32] 0)
out: 0 : ([32] ([13 32] 0))
out: 2x^2-x-1=0 : ([] ([0] ([0 0] ([0 0 0] ([0 0 0 0] ([15 0 0 0 0] ([53 15 0 0 0 0] 2) ([54 15 0 0 0 0] x))) ^ ([20 0 0 0] ([13 20 0 0 0] 2))) - ([29 0 0] ([13 29 0 0] x))) - ([29 0] ([13 29 0] 1))) = ([32] ([13 32] 0)))
(2x)^2 - x - 1 = 0
```

Comment: Both `expression` and `simplifiedMultiplication` have the `*` as optional. Why is that? If you remove the `?` from `expression '*'? expression`, things should go as you want them to go.

Comment: @BartKiers: Thx for your reply! simplifiedMultiplication was just an (unsuccessful) trial. If I remove the question mark (?) then 5x won't match, just 5*x.

Comment: No, leave the question mark in `simplifiedMultiplication` but remove it from the alternative: `| expression '*'? expression`.

Comment: @BartKiers: I've tried it but in this case I get an error while parsing (I use listeners and a stack to create appropriate Java objects): the simplifiedMultiplication gets 5x as input but the stack does not contain either the 5 or the x as the appropriate listeners (NATURAL and VARIABLE) have not been called. Strange.

Comment: Can you post your listener class?

Comment: @Onur: Listener class added to the post. Please note everything has been working (having the only rule `expression *? expression` for multiplications) until I added the negation rule.

Comment: "2 x^2" is not a `simpleMultiplication` - at least not in the current form of your rule! To get the precedence right, I think you need to move it into the expression rule (not sure about that). There's a reason, why many languages don't allow this kind of multiplication!

Comment: Another option would be to allow more simple multiplication that is "really" allowed and check for errors later on.

Comment: @Onur: I know that `2 x^2` is currently not a `simpleMultiplication` but I have no idea how to make it properly parsed. Furthermore could you please elaborate more on your last hint (Another option would be to allow more simple multiplication that is "really" allowed and check for errors later on.)!?! What do you mean with "check for errors later on"?

Comment: Allow something to be parsed although it's invalid. E.g. even if you don't want to allow x^2 x^2 to be valid, allow  it to be successful parsed.

Comment: @Onur: I've added the rule `| primary expression` to `simpleMultiplication` but the expression `2x^2 - 5x` is still parsed as `(2x)^2 - 5x`.